# Stress Testing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, testing, stress-testing

Visual Studio 2008 has a test type called a Load Test.  It looks like I can just drop a collection of other tests into it, give it a test profile (say, 50 users constantly hitting the program), a running time, and let it run.

What isn't clear to me, is how to actually setup the tests it consumes.  I need to launch a instance of the program to be tested (technically, a HTTP server; but not a web project or anything - just a console app) with some command line parameters, and have it remain up while the actual tests are running.

Basically, how would I setup a Load Test (or any test) in Visual Studio 2008 that would allow me to startup a project, then run a number of tests against it - in a configuration of my choosing as in Load Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of doing it is to create a [LoadTestPlugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153(VS.80).aspx) to do what you want at various points in the load test.

The events exposed are:

- LoadTestStarting
- LoadTestFinished
- LoadTestWarmupComplete
- TestStarting
- TestFinished
- ThresholdExceeded
- HeartBeat
- LoadTestAborted